# Mint Edition from MasterEdition says account is missing

Tags: anchor, metaplex, minteditionfrommaster

I am trying to mint a edition from a master edition with the following metaplex function:

```
let accounts = vec![
        ctx.accounts.new_metadata.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.new_edition.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.new_mint.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.edition_mark_pda.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.new_mint_authority.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_account_owner.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.new_metadata_update_authority.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
    ];
    invoke(
        &mint_new_edition_from_master_edition_via_token(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
            ctx.accounts.new_metadata.key(),
            ctx.accounts.new_edition.key(),
            ctx.accounts.master_edition.key(),
            ctx.accounts.new_mint.key(),
            ctx.accounts.new_mint_authority.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            ctx.accounts.token_account_owner.key(),
            ctx.accounts.token_account.key(),
            ctx.accounts.new_metadata_update_authority.key(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
            1,
        ),
        &accounts,
    )?;
```

Unfortunatly I always receive this error:

```
'Program log: Instruction: MintEdition',
    'Instruction references an unknown account F5mAJWXVpQ4rupmvMGTY7ZDqK7UUzSkS7dTfTRX6WMLf',
    'Program 4euwMgqxB9GkxVBY7uXKRRuC68yhkNbsVUhDPYS1mbhD consumed 18852 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program 4euwMgqxB9GkxVBY7uXKRRuC68yhkNbsVUhDPYS1mbhD failed: An account required by the instruction is missing'
```

My function call from the frontend looks like the following:

```
await program.methods
            .mintEdition()
            .accounts({
                newMetadata: metadataAddress,
                newEdition: newEditionAddress,
                masterEdition: masterEditionAddress,
                newMint: newMint.publicKey,
                editionMarkPda: editionMarkPda,
                newMintAuthority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                payer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                tokenAccountOwner: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                tokenAccount: ata,
                newMetadataUpdateAuthority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                metadata: metadataAddress,
                tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            })
            .rpc();
```

This is how I get the editionMarkPda in the frontend:

```
await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [
        Buffer.from("metadata"),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        masterEditionMint.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        Buffer.from("edition"),
        Buffer.from("1"),
    ],
    TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
)
```

Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: It's probable that you're generating one of the PDAs wrongly. The `edition_mark_pda` is an easy one to get wrong. Can you show how you're generating it on your frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deriving `editionMarkPda` like this; It's what worked for me:

```
const EDITION_MARKER_BIT_SIZE = 248;
let edition = 1; // your edition in this case is 1

let editionNumber = new anchor.BN(Math.floor(edition/EDITION_MARKER_BIT_SIZE));
console.log("editionNumber: ", editionNumber.toString());

let editionMarkPda = (await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress([
  Buffer.from("metadata"), TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(), masterEditionMint.publicKey.toBuffer(),
  Buffer.from("edition"), Buffer.from(editionNumber.toString())], TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
))[0];
```

Comment: Thank you that helped, unfortunatly I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: It's tricky to pinpoint the offending account in these kinds of cases. Try logging your public keys in your frontend to see which matches the "unknown account". 

If you can share a link to a github repo, I could look through it

Comment: When logging all accounts I am passing to the instruction via the frontend none matches the unknown account which is irritating me. Did you receive a message on discord? I would provide my github there. Thanks a lot for you help.